# perpendicular bisector of AB

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $A(-6,9)$ and $B(10,-3)$ be points in the plane
Find an equation of the perpendicular bisector of $AB$
the answer I get is $y=(4/3)x+(1/3)$ but it is not correct.

Comment: And how did you arrive at your answer?

Comment: @rick, Please share your steps

Comment: You got the slope right. For the rest, note that the perpendicular bisector goes through the midpoint of the segment $AB$. You will get $y=\frac{4}{3}x+\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: It looks right to me; the slope should be $4/3$, and it should go through the midpoint (2,3).

Comment: Did your answer get rejected by a computer? Maybe it (correctly) objected to your writing 4/3*x instead of (4/3)*x.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it (with details omitted):

- Find the midpoint $P$ of the line segment.  (How?)
- Find the slope of the line segment.  (How?)
- Find the slope of a line perpendicular to the line segment.  (How?)
- Find the line of that slope that goes through $P$.  (Using what equation?)

Comment: MP=(2,3)
slope=-3/4

Comment: Those are correct for the first two parts.  What about the other two parts?

Comment: +1 for asking how. For the last part, I like this formula $m=\Delta y / \Delta x$

Answer (score 1):

**Your answer is correct**. (Maybe, the answer you saw is wrong.)

- The midpoint of the line segment $AB$ is $((-6+10)/2,(9-3)/2)=(2,3)$.
- The slope of the line $AB$ is $(-3-9)/(10-(-6))=-3/4$. Hence, the slope of the line we want is $4/3$. (Why?)

These lead that the answer is $y-3=(4/3)(x-2)\iff y=(4/3)x+(1/3)$, which is *what you wrote as your answer*.

Comment: Thanks for showing that the OP's answer was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Say $C$ is the mid-point of line segment $AB$.
So $C=(2,3)$

And slope of $AB$ is $\frac{-3}{4}$

Hence, slope of line-segment perpendicular to $AB$ is $\frac{4}{3}$

And hence, equation of perpendicular bisector of $AB$ is: $(y-3)=\frac{4}{3}$$(x-2)$

Solving this,  $3y-4x=1$  is the required equation.

Answer (score 0):

Slope....midpoint ..... egad! Just find an equation for the set of points that are equidistant from both points $A$ and $B$.

**hint**: its easier to find the square of the distance than the distance, much easier than figuring out this diagram.

[image]

Comment: OK, the quadratic terms cancel out very quickly, but still, how is this less work?

Comment: it just eliminates a lot of thinking, which is perfect on hot summer days when I should be drinking lemonade instead :)

Comment: @DavidK I agree with John Joy for the reason of (1) the thinking logic is more direct; (2) one less formula to use; (3) the required equation comes right out after simplification.

Comment: The perpendicular bisector of $AB$ is _defined_ as the line perpendicular to $AB$ through the midpoint of $AB$, so constructing it that way seems to use the most direct thinking logic, although the equidistant property is one of the first one learns about the bisector, so it is not _much_ less direct. Part (b) depends on how readily one remembers (or can derive) the formula for slope of a perpendicular line. I'll grant you, the equidistant method does require a little less geometric thinking in that respect.

Comment: I realize that the goal of posing a problem like this to a student is to have him/her use the midpoint formula, understand the relationship between the slopes of perpendicular lines, and to express a line in point-slope form. It just seems to me that this approach encourages students to just parrot back standard algorithms, instead of thinking for themselves. e.g. How many of you just assumed the proclamation that a line of slope $m$ is perpendicular to one of slope $-\frac{1}{m}$ to be true? I say, reason it out, then apply it.